# Can't access pre populated SQLite database using PhoneGap/Cordova in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

We are trying to create a mobile app using PhoneGap/Cordova. We need to ship this app with a pre-populated SQLite db. We are able to copy the DB using below code. But when we try to access tables from copied DB in our App we get 'No Such Table' error. Can anyone help us in identifying the cause ?

We copied the database using the below code to data/data/package_name/databases folder.

```
   try
    {
        File dbFile = getDatabasePath("Bee_dict.db");
        if(!dbFile.exists()){
            this.copy("Bee_dict.db",dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }


//And our copy function:

   void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException
    {
     File CheckDirectory;
     CheckDirectory = new File(folder);


     String parentPath = CheckDirectory.getParent();

     File filedir = new File(parentPath);
     if (!filedir.exists()) {
         if (!filedir.mkdirs()) {
             return;
         }
     }

        InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        File newfile = new File(folder);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);


        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close(); out.close();
    }
```

index.html
The below code is used to open and access the DB

```
 function onDeviceReady()
 {
  db = window.openDatabase("Bee_dict", "1.0", "Bee_dict", 20000);
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM data WHERE word_id = ?', [1], querySuccess_definition, errorCB);
 }
```

Cordova version - 2.9

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first place, can trying with the next DB file name:

```
0000000000000001.db
```

And for load file:

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath(".0000000000000001db");
```

The DB file needs to be in the next route:

```
yourProyect/assets/0000000000000001.db
```

I recommend use "SQLitePlugin":

[SQLitePlugin GitHub](https://github.com/brodybits/PhoneGap-sqlite-plugin-rebuild/blob/master/Android/assets/www/SQLitePlugin.js)

In the "onDeviceReady()" function i use:

```
if(!dbCreated){
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("0000000000000001", "1.0", "My Database", -1);
}
```

Comment: Working fine in jellybean and ics but not working in gingerbread.

Comment: https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.

This plugin works perfect.

Comment: Thanks @KratosBala Updated link: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but the answer above does not help me, so I am writing my experience, it may help.

I typically used a Cordova plugin named: me.rahul.plugins.sqlDB at https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy

It is a plugin focused to copy files from Cordova www folder to the right folder on Android/iphone.

You have first to install the plugin, using:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy.git
```

Then on Device Ready event:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(">device is ready");
    window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("mydb.sqlite", copySuccess, copyError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access pre-populated database you should first copy the database file in www directory.

Install this plugin [DB-Copy plugin](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy) and copy the database from **www** directory into the device, using the copy plugin and then use [Sqlite-storage plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) to access the database.

PS. The copy of database from **www** directory is need it because each OS has different location to store databases...