# Pre-populated sqlite database issue in cordova android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to create `'Offline Dictionary Android App` Using Cordova. I have created sqlite database using `SQLite database browser`. The database file is `test.db` and it has one table `test` with two fields '_id' which is `INTEGER` `PRIMARY KEY` and 'value' which is `TEXT`. Some records are also inserted.

I have tried these with no luck :

1. [import/export to android sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537145/import-export-to-android-sqlite-database)
2. [Can't access pre populated SQLite database using PhoneGap/Cordova in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014419/cant-access-pre-populated-sqlite-database-using-phonegap-cordova-in-android)

I have been able to collect the following code. 
I want my third attempt to be successful so I am here to ask for a help with experts.

***WHAT I HAVE DONE***

I put the `test.db` sqlite database file in the `assets` directory of my android project. I have `MainActivity.java` File which has the following code :

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        try{
            System.out.println("----------Copying Database -----------");
                copyDataBase("test.db");

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("----------Error Copying Database -----------");
            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

    private void copyDataBase(String dbname) throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        String pkg = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        InputStream myInput = this.getAssets().open(dbname);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = "/data/data/"+ pkg + "/databases/" + dbname;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

}
```

and `script.js` file with the following script :

***script.js***

```
(function($, undefined){

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady(){

        var db = window.openDatabase(
            'test.db',
            '1.0.0',
            'Test Database',
            64 * 1024
        );

        db.transaction(function(tx){

            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM test', [], function(tx, result){

                    console.log("Query Success");
                    console.log('Total Rows :' + result.rows.length);

                },function(tx, error) {
                    console.log('An Error Occured (Qry) : ' + error.message);
                }
            )

        }, function(error){

            console.log('An Error Occured : ' + error.message);

        }, function(){
            console.log("Transaction Success");
        })

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I have launched my app in both `emulator` and the `physical device` and got the same error response that says 'no such table : test'. I found the `test.db` insdie `data/data/MY_PACKAGE/databases/`. I `pulled` that database file using eclipse and opened in `SQLite Database browser` and there is `test` table with some records that I have populated.

I am using cordova 2.6.0 and testing my app on android 4.2 . My device is not rooted (ignore if it does not affect).

The screen shot which visualizes the scenario :
[image]

**Why am I getting the 'no such table' error even there is a table ?**

Please Help.

Comment: Waiting for the response till 1Hr. No helpful hands yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you have done the connect in the database correctly, then create a table, insert some data, then select what you did put on the table, from Cordova and the Database Browser.

Maybe you dont need to put .db, try this code first

```
var db = window.openDatabase(
        'test',
        '1.0.0',
        'Test Database',
        64 * 1024
    );

db.transaction(function populateDB(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');

},function errorCB(tx, err) {

    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);

},function successCB() {

    alert("success!");

});
```

Comment: I am trying to use pre-populdated database where I would have the  `database` , `table` and some records in it. I can't use cordova for creating the `table` and inserting  the records because I have 100000+ records. I have tried 'test' instead of 'test.db' but getting the same error.

Comment: I mean try to pre-populate to check if you are using the database you want. Use just a fill datas to check it.

Comment: I am getting the same error with and without the `.db` extension, and the `error.message` is also `undefined` which is making it hard to debug, do you have any idea please

Comment: Try the code that I add in the answer, also try to remove the parameter size of database.

Comment: `check if you are using the database you want` was really helpful. I changed the `databases` to `app_database` and seems the error `no such table` no longer exists. Thank you for your useful comment. And yes `test.db` is not needed now `test` is doing the job. It's 12 : 30 AM here , going to bed, good nite.

Comment: When you wake, if you got a problme just comment here!

Answer (score 0):

I completely test your code. I solved writing the complete path in js code:

```
var db = window.openDatabase(
        '/data/data/com.example.myapp/databases/test.db',
        '1.0.0',
        'Test Database',
        64 * 1024
    );
```

..and a project clean before re-run the project.

Hope this help you.

Regards